Confidence intervals on means of proportions (with possibly asymmetry)
I'm working through some reporting of a survey and trying to get my head around the appropriate calculation of the margin of error. (I'm giving feedback, these aren't my calculations so I'm not in a position to recalculate anything).
There are 9 Likert items (5 point scale), each has been turned in to a binary (true/false). For each participant who answered at least 5 of the 9 items, the proportion true is calculated. The mean of those proportions is calculated to get an "overall proportion true".
The margin of error is quoted using the basic formula:  1.96*sqrt(p(1-p)/n) where p is the overall proportion true. To me, this doesn't seem right as it doesn't account for the fact that different individuals could have answered different numbers of items. Also, the I'm not sure whether average of proportions (vs. a straight proportion) also needs accounting for.
How would you approach the margin of error in this scenario? Would that approach change if all participants had answered all of the items?

I would consider bootstrapping..

Because not all subjects answered the same number of questions (you said "5 or more"), you can not do an average of proportions (as this would overvalue the subjects with, say, only 5 answers, vs. the subjects with 9 answers). One should instead use the total counts of "true", over all subjects to get the "overall proportion true" (let's call this statistic, $p$).
Now, for computing a confidence interval (CI) for $p$, the first, obvious choice, would be to use a binomial CI (aka Clopper-Pearson, aka "exact") (after all, by now, you just have a single binomial variable). E.g. here, you can find an excellent online calculator for it.
Chances are however that, because the total sample size will be large (~9*"number of subjects"), the number of "true" may be "large" (traditionally, more than 5 or 10). Therefore, one could be tempted to use "normal approximations" to this binomial CI. Note that if number of trues is rather small, any normal approximation is not valid (as the binomial distribution will not look normal at all).
In this case, the formula you quote is simply a z-score (aka Wald interval), and is an albeit basic, but still a correct normal approximation. A better normal approximation may be the Wilson score. And there are many others; wiki's page is a good place to read about all the "flavors".
The calculator I linked above computes Wald, Wilson, and Clopper-Pearson, and gives didactic formulas and graphs.
Note that when the total counts (true & false) and true counts are large, the various flavors all will give you very similar CIs; so you can plug the numbers from your study (after correcting the "overall proportion true"!) and see what the various flavors give... My personal take is that, if you find substantial differences between the CIs, use the Clopper-Pearson, but others find it too "conservative". I will leave that debate for another answer. And of course if they are quite similar, use any...
One last comment (which you did not ask about): when reducing the Likert data to binary true/false, the original researchers lost a lot of information, which is not generally considered good practice. If they had kept it, one could use more sophisticated analysis than a simple binomial CI.

(I'm not sure I fully understand the setup) One should instead use the total counts of "true", over all subjects to get the "overall proportion true": On the other hand, if a subject has answered many more questions than the others (not really a possibility here since at most there are 9 answers/subject), that subject will have too much say in the final proportion. E.g. n_true = c(1, 3, 5, 4); n_answers = c(5, 6, 7, 90). Option 1 (average of proportions): mean(n_true / n_answers) = 0.365; option 2 (proportion from totals): sum(n_true) / sum(n_answers) = 0.12

@dariober, exactly! Your example illustrates the issue. Subject 1 had 1 true from 5 tries, or p=20%. But the CI for this proportion is [.005,.716]. Subject 4 had 4 true from 90 tries or p=4.44%. But its CI is [.01,.11], much tighter! By just averaging them, I give both estimates the same weight even when they have very different margins of error. Using proportions from total essentially averages the proportions, but weighted by the counts for each user (as it should be, because of the different margins of error).  ...ctd

...ctd. One can look at it from another lens. When using the Wald interval, with your example, what value of $n$ should one use? 108? Not if  you are averaging the proportions; you could use 4 (you have 4 -but non i.d. !- estimates of the proportion)? Or you could subsample say 6 observations from subject 4 (to get similar # of tries for each subject) and use $n=24$. But if you are using the total observations, you use 108. Now, if this was a real experiment, I would not do any analysis on this dat, as it basically only has 1 subject. I may subsample (and lose power), or collect more data.
